# Puppet DSC module: Could not evaluate: Convert property 'authenticationinfo' value from type 'INSTANCE[]' to type 'INSTANCE' failed

Tags: puppet, dsc

I'm attempting to use `dsc_authenticationinfo => {"Anonymous"=>false, "Basic"=>false, "Digest"=>false, "Windows"=>true},` getting `could not evaluate` error below.  This property is inside of dsc_xwebsite{}.

```
dsc_xwebsite{$app_dns_name:
  dsc_ensure                    => 'Present',
  dsc_name                      => $app_dns_name,
  dsc_state                     => 'Started',
  dsc_physicalpath              => $app_webroot_path,
  dsc_applicationpool           => $app_pool_name,
  dsc_bindinginfo               => [{
    protocol => 'HTTP',
    port     => 80,
    hostname => $app_dns_name,
  }],
  dsc_authenticationinfo => {"Anonymous"=>true, "Basic"=>true, "Digest"=>true, "Windows"=>true},
}
```

I'm getting the following error on my windows 2012 R2 host.

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Profiles::Iis_tools/Dsc_xwebsite[tools-dev.domain.com]: Could not evaluate: Convert property 'authenticationinfo' value from type 'INSTANCE[]' to type 'INSTANCE' failed
 At line:31, char:2
 Buffer:
ls-dev.domain.com";
};^

insta
```

Comment: Ok I went in the wrong direction on this one potentially. Is your `$app_dns_name` being passed as a string? It should be like `$app_dns_name = 'ls-dev.domain.com'` and not `$app_dns_name = ls-dev.domain.com`. Your `dsc_bindinginfo` can probably be a hash instead of an array of a hash according to the `dsc_xwebsite` type source code by the way.

Comment: No it's not ls-dev.domain.com.  It's supposed to be tools-dev.domain.com - but for some reason the error message cuts off 'too'.  Puppet brings $app_dns_name in as a string via hiera lookup.  I'm fairly sure the lookup is done properly because other things are using the variable properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with 1) documentation on Microsoft's DSC code.  2) Improper implementation in puppetlabs\dsc module.  The MS documentation was fixed and the DSC module was fixed as of version 1.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Puppet syntax, but comparing your puppet code to some working DSC below, it seems like your authentication code should be formatted more like your bind code, so

```
dsc_authenticationinfo => 
  {"Anonymous"=>true, "Basic"=>true, "Digest"=>true, "Windows"=>true},
```

should be:

```
dsc_authenticationinfo => 
  {dsc_anonymous => true, dsc_basic => true, dsc_digest => true, dsc_windows => true},
```

However, your error message:

> "Convert property 'authenticationinfo' value from type 'INSTANCE[]' to
>   type 'INSTANCE' failed"

indicates you are passing an array when a single authenticationinfo is expected?   Your dsc_authenticationinfo value is not in square brackets which looks correct to me; I'm hoping the code you posted and the error message are just out of sync, and the code change above will fix your issue.

For reference, this is valid DSC code.  And note that BindingInfo is an array of one while AuthenticationInfo is a single instance:

```
  xWebSite DefaultWebSite_Site
  {
       Name = "Default Web Site"
       Ensure = "Present"
       State = "Started"
       ApplicationPool = "DefaultAppPool"
       PhysicalPath = "%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot"  # must already exist
       LogPath = "D:\IISLogs"
       DependsOn = "[xWebAppPool]DefaultAppPool_Pool"
       BindingInfo = 
                 @(
                      MSFT_xWebBindingInformation 
                      {
                           Protocol = "http"
                           Port = "80"
                           IPAddress = "*"
                      }
                 )
       AuthenticationInfo = 
                 MSFT_xWebAuthenticationInformation 
                 {
                      Anonymous = $true
                      Basic = $false
                      Digest = $false
                      Windows = $false
                 }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  Unfortunately I've tried it with and without quotes around the authentication properties and with and without brackets but can't get it to work in puppet..

Thanks for that syntax.  it did work in DSC.  I'm not sure if this is a bug in puppet's module.

Comment: The documentation on xwebadministration's github says that both bindinginfo and authenticationinfo are expected to be arrays.

Comment: FWIW,  I think the DSC documentation is wrong to say AuthenticationInfo is an array.  Looking at the [source](https://github.com/PowerShell/xWebAdministration/blob/dev/DSCResources/MSFT_xWebsite/MSFT_xWebsite.schema.mof), lines 31 and 34, I see a BindingInfo[] type and AuthenticationInfo type without the brackets.  I'll raise an issue with them about the documentation.

Comment: Looking at the (puppet code)[https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-dsc/blob/545f5f4f218b7850b12cb38f51349e5733e9c19b/lib/puppet/type/dsc_xwebsite.rb], ...it follows the documentation rather than actual implementation so that explains the casting error.  @FuriousD check out xWebsite issue #223 for more details on the DSC side.